# Counting keyword in the file

Tags: python

I am trying to count the keywords in a `.py` file but the code I wrote is also counting keywords which occur in strings.
How can I differentiate between actual keywords and the ones in strings? For example: `is`, `with` and `in` are keywords, but you can also spot those in comments and user input strings. This is what I have tried:

```
from collections import Counter
import keyword

count = {}
scode = input("Enter the name of Python source code file name :")
with open(scode,'r') as f:
    for line in f:
         words = line.split()
         for i in words:
             if(keyword.iskeyword(i)):
                 count[i]= count.get(i,0)+1
     print(count)
```

Comment: If you want to be able to differentiate between code, string literals and comments, you will have to do actual code parsing, rather than just searching for words. Expect that to be much much more complex than your current code.

Comment: If you are serious about this you should probably have a look at the [ast](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/ast.html#module-ast) module. I imagine you will hit a number of corner-cases using regexps.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `ast.parse` to parse the code, create a `ast.NodeTransformer` subclass to clear all the string nodes (no need to clear comments because comments are automatically ignored by `ast.parse` already), install the [`astunparse` package](https://github.com/simonpercivall/astunparse) to turn the node back to source code, and then count the keywords:

```
import ast
import astunparse
import keyword
import re

class clear_strings(ast.NodeTransformer):
    def visit_Str(self, node):
        node.s = ''
        return node

n = ast.parse('''
a = 'True'
assert False
# [[] for _ in range(9)]
"""if"""
''')

clear_strings().visit(n)
print(sum(map(keyword.iskeyword, re.findall(r'\w+', astunparse.unparse(n)))))
```

This outputs: `2` (because only `assert` and `False` are counted as keywords)

Comment: Just curious, will `elif` be restored as well or will it be replaced with a nested `else if `?

Comment: `elif` is a valid Python keyword just like `if` and `else`, so it will be restored as well.

Comment: Sorry, I imagined a solution that was using the ast to *find* the keywords, but your code is just removing the "distractions" and then checking the remainder for keywords - elegant!

Comment: Good answer `*_*`